# How to add UPROPERTY() macro within a c++ Macro

Tags: c++, properties, macros, unreal-engine4

I want to have items created using c++ macros like this:

```
#define PROPERTIES\
UPROPERTY(blabla)\
variableType varName;\
UPROPERTY(blabla)\
variableType2 varName2;
```

So I can add properties to other files including this and using PROPERTIES macro on them.

```
class XYZ...
{

...

public:
      PROPERTIES

      ...
      UPROPERTY()
      varibleType3 name3;
      ....
}
```

This design comes from a typical organization, where those parameters come from another class because they are related to that class.

So I could include diferent files, and include all properties to show in the editor from all of them.

What's happening is that the Unreal Header Tool completely ignores UPROPERTY, of course, probably because it's being processed before and then the Macro... surprisingly is working but only the variable, not UPROPERTY... So the editor doesn't show it.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that your properties are defined correctly? You should use something like `UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, Category="My category")` **Category** is required when exposing Functions or Properties to editor. Properties with this macro would be exposed to instance properties editor and to class defaults editor as well.

Also I'd like to point out, that this design is really poor and I think that you may have problems with it. As you correctly pointed out, Epic has *custom* reflection system (UHT)which allows you to use automatic memory management with GC and so on. More on Build System [UE Docs](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Programming/UnrealBuildSystem/).

I think that you should decide how those properties will be used. Since you want to distribute them over multiple *actors*, you can choose from:

1. Inheritance
2. UObject reference
3. Component system

The first is really trivial and I believe you are familiar with this concept. And I think that you had your reasons why chose that *macro* solution. **Note** that you aren't allowed to use multiple inheritance (which is possible in classic C++) and this is due to UBT.

The second one goes like this:

```
UCLASS(BlueprintType)
class UMyProps : public UObject
{
     // TODO define properties in a standard way
}

// some actor's properties
UPROPERTY(BlueprintReadWrite, Category = "My Game | My Subcategory")
UMyProps* myProperties;
```

Main advantage of the second system is that you can add sets of properties to objects that requires them while having type-safe environment and full Intellisence support (and UE Editor as well of course).

Or you can use **Components**, which is more or less like the second approach, but it could be totally dynamic (you don't need actual reference to your component, you can get it by calling `GetComponent(...)`).

These three are good, solid and transparent approaches to extend your object's properties. By using your *macro*'s approach, you could easily ends up with a mountain of a mess, if this even works with UE build system).

Comment: Thanks for the related info, Pavel. Let me explain: including variables using macros seems like a very common approach. I was told to do so by a very experienced programmer. It's maybe wrong in Unreal, though. We thought maybe UPROPERTY macro was modified by Unreal Header Tool BEFORE PROPERTIES macro is used. That's why we thought maybe the UHT was breaking the code of the PROPERTIES macro.

I didn't know I could use a "UCLASS" to include the properties. I was starting to use a struct instead, because I'm putting it inside an already existing class, as a complement.  I'll test it

Comment: @darkgaze You need to specify `UCLASS` or `USTRUCT` so that `class` or `struct` could be find by UHT. Then you need to correctly use `UPROPERTY` (https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/89949/uproperty-not-reflecting-in-editor.html) The same mecanism applies to `UFUNCTION` (For exemple if you want to use C++ introduced delegates, you can add use only `UFUNCTION()` (To be continued)

Comment: @darkgaze (continue) (see https://forums.unrealengine.com/community/community-content-tools-and-tutorials/13915-tutorial-creating-and-using-delegates-c-and-accessing-them-in-blueprints?30345-Tutorial-Creating-and-Using-Delegates-C-and-Accessing-them-in-Blueprints=). But if you want to call some function from *Blueprint*, you need to mark it like `UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable, Category = "MyCategory")`. Once you are familiar with this concept, it will be really simple to you extend your code and expose new things to Blueprints.

Comment: Thanks Pavel. We don't use blueprints. Our functionality is quite low level and we don't like visual representations for now. Btw, checked with the guy who told me to do this. He said your idea is much better and that, while the Macro thing is common, is not as clean as the struct/class solution. :-)

Comment: You are welcome. And I'm pleased to hear compliments from an experienced guy, since I've learned game programming all by myself and I know there is a lot of good stuff and gamedev practises I'm not aware about.

Comment: :)  He pretty much did the same as you... many years. Btw, I just tested the UPROPERTY inside a simple MACRO, using EditAnywhere, and it doesn't show up. Not even using a struct variable for that UPROPERTY. Nah, it doesn't show up.  UPROPERTY inside a c++ macro... not a good idea.

Comment: I know this is very old thread by now, but the way UHT works is it does not EXPAND macros. It is just string processing, so if you put your custom macro in the file, that is what UHT sees. Just the name of the macro, not the expanded version done by preprocessor.